# System.Web.UI.Control.Visible=False vs set System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Attributes Style "display none"

Tags: asp.net

As the title show. Can anyone tell me what is the difference of these two? There are both used for hiding the element marked with `runat=server` in the code-behind. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Visible false property is set; control will not be rendered onto browser (document.getElementById gives null)

With display:none that is not the case. It will be on browser but hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the control when the html is rendered on the browser in case of `display:none` by changing it from the developer toolbar, but in case of `System.Web.UI.Control.Visible=False` the control itself is not rendered in the browser.